# How to mount host directory in docker container using remote api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, docker, docker-machine

Using the docker remote api. How can i mount a local directory from the machine that's making the request to the the machine that's running docker. Can someone show me an example request to "POST /containers/create" route that mounts a local directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, the remote HTTP API request can be coming from anywhere, and doesn't have access to your local drive in the request. If HTTP gave full access of your local drive to any site you accessed, any malicious website would have full access to your PC without any exploit required.

To access your drive with a remote request like this, you either need to have that drive mounted on the Docker host (e.g. VM running the Docker engine), and then mount that, or you need to share your directory, and use a volume driver like NFS to access the remote directory.